# Mongodb cheat sheet collection

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

This should be some sort of Mongodb Cheatsheet collection. Only selected Cheat Sheets are provided. If you're have a Cheat Sheet, just add it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There're also some good examples for raw aggregation, after scrawling down.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/sql-aggregation-comparison/

Answer (score 1):

1. Basics, really recommend

https://gist.github.com/bradtraversy/f407d642bdc3b31681bc7e56d95485b6

2. Level two, much more in use.

https://gist.github.com/ondrejsika/ded2a9a22c96cda7098d69b5f158cd8a